# Generating Sequence Numbers (Oracle equivalent) in AWS Ecosystem

Tags: amazon-web-services, sequence, amazon-dynamodb

For many of us moving to AWS serverless and NoSql DB DynamoDB from traditional RDBMS Oracle, it may be puzzling to find an easy way to generate sequence numbers.
One way is to use the atomic counter is a number attribute in a DynamoDB table that can be used to update the value atomically.
We can create a table order-number-sequence that has a partition key (id) and a sequence number attribute. Then create API and utilize API Gateway’s built-in integration for DynamoDB.

Is there any better way to generate sequence numbers in AWS ecosystem (with database as DynamoDB)?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you need sequence _numbers_ or can you switch to a UUID?

Comment: We need numbers. UUID is a banging 4 times larger than the normal 4-byte index value. We need sequential numbers and if we use UUID new records are inserted at random positions because UUID is not sequential.

Comment: DynamoDB lets you use transactions, so you can do a transactional update of an item that contains the sequence value. However, everything in your comment says to me that DynamoDB is absolutely the wrong technology choice for your use case.

Comment: Agree for seq generation but question is if we have to find out atomic number generation techniques in AWS ecosystem.